# Why doesn't the "code --help" command display help in Command Prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line, running the "code --help" command in Command Prompt should display help or usage information. However, when I run the command in Command Prompt, VS Code opens like it does when I click its icon from the taskbar. Why doesn't the "code --help" command display help when I run it in Command Prompt?

## Additional information

Running ">Help: About" in VS Code's palette outputs the following:

```
Version: 1.87.2 (user setup)
Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
Date: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

I can't remember if I installed VS Code via the Microsoft Store or the installer obtained by clicking on the "Download for Windows" button on https://code.visualstudio.com.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. also, how _exactly_ did you install VS Code?